# How do I use bundler to get a gem from a git repository?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Authlogic has a couple [unfortunate deprecation warnings](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/issuesearch?state=open&q=save%28false%29+is+deprecated#issue/161) that are fixed in a [fork](https://github.com/railsware/authlogic).

How do I use this forked version? I tried adding the following to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'authlogic', :git => 'git://github.com/railsware/authlogic.git'
```

And it didn't work quite that well. I started getting:

> git://github.com/railsware/authlogic.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`

And

> The git source git://github.com/railsware/authlogic.git is not yet checked out. Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application

Assistance will be rewarded with [virtual cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried running bundle install after removing Gemfile.lock?

```
rm Gemfile.lock
bundle install
```

Your Gemfile configuration should work, I was able to use the same for and my bundle install command executes as does my bundle list command.

My other suggestion would be removing you ~/.bundler and .bundle directories and checking that you have properly configured git.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I followed the steps though, and I'm still getting "git://github.com/railsware/authlogic.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`" when running `bundle list`.

Comment: I updated my post with some other suggestions - I was able to get your example working just fine on my own machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `bundle install` from the terminal after updating your `Gemfile`.